# Building model tree from string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

So I've been bashing my head against a wall for a while on this one. What Im attempting to do is follow through a category trace defined as "category>child category> child of child category..." but for some reason, of which I am clearly failing to grasp, The categories that should have a parent sometimes fail to set their ParentId, not all the time though!?

```
string catString = "Category1Name>Category2Name>Category3Name";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(catString)) {
            string[] catStrings = catString.Split('>');
            ProductCategory[] categories = new ProductCategory[catStrings.Length];

            for (int j = 0; j < catStrings.Length; j++) {
                string categoryName = catStrings[j];
                ProductCategory parent = j > 0 ? categories[j - 1] : null;

                if (j > 0) {
                    categories[j] = _context.ProductCategories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToUpper().Replace(" ", "") == categoryName.ToUpper().Replace(" ", "") && x.ParentId == parent.Id);
                } else {
                    categories[j] = _context.ProductCategories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToUpper().Replace(" ", "") == categoryName.ToUpper().Replace(" ", ""));
                }

                if (categories[j] == null) {
                    if (j > 0) {
                        categories[j] = new ProductCategory { Name = categoryName, ParentId = parent.Id };

                        if (parent.Children == null) {
                            parent.Children = new List<ProductCategory>();
                        }

                        parent.Children.Add(categories[j]);
                    } else {
                        categories[j] = new ProductCategory { Name = categoryName };
                    }

                    _context.ProductCategories.Add(categories[j]);
                    categoriesCreated++;
                }
            }

            product.Category = categories.Last();
        }
```

A Category is defined as such

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int ParentId { get; set; }
public virtual List<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; }
```

String Examples

```
Glassware>Shot Glasses
Glassware>Wine Glasses
Glassware>Glass Carafes/Decanters/Jugs>Glass Carafes
Glassware>Glass Carafes/Decanters/Jugs>Glass Jugs
Tableware>Cutlery>Premium 18/10
```

Comment: I'd look into the System.Xml namespace or System.Xml.Linq namespace, and see about using that to create a tree structure as an XmlDocument or XDocument, you can then convert that to a string. Also, it looks like you are using entity-framework, you could always write your own SQL Procedure and have it return your data as XML.

Comment: I'm trying to create the models from the string rather than turning the models into a string. The reason for this is I'm trying to import product data from a csv, The problem I seem to be having is that I've messed up setting up the relationships but Im not able to see where. Sorry for the terrible explanation.

Comment: Where do you save changes to the database? Is the Ids on the parents auto generated in the database, since you just call `new ProductCategory { Name = categoryName };` or where do you set the Ids? And you should probably set up your models so that the FK is automatically set.

Comment: @JamesAnderson - can you edit your question to post a few rows of actual string data at the bottom?

Comment: This is contained within a loop that loops through each of the rows of the csv and so the changes are saved once the loop has exited. Im using entity-framework that, as far as I know, Handles the Ids. It definitely has set up the foreign keys. Ive edited the post to include some examples of the incoming string data.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this works, using a [TreeNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx) object to contain everything.

```
public class SO50846156
{

    public TreeNode Test(String[] data)
    {
        var root = new TreeNode();
        foreach (var line in data)
        {
            var split = line.Split('>');
            var count = split.Length;
            var item = root.Nodes.Add(split[0]);
            if (1 < count)
            {
                var subCat = item.Nodes.Add(split[1]);
                if (2 < count)
                {
                    var catName = subCat.Nodes.Add(split[2]);
                }
            }
        }
        return root;
    }

}
```

The root element gets created every time, and you get a node for each line of your data.

I'm not sure what yours is trying to accomplish that is different, but maybe this gives you some ideas.

Comment: The issue with this is that each string isn't always describing a unique tree. As the example strings show Glassware etc. appear multiple times and each time it needs to point to the same node, hopefully that makes sense.